# Force Android to show all copies of identical notification icons

Tags: android, notifications

My app can accept multiple client connections and I want it to display a status bar icon for each connection with a little indicator to show activity from this client.

If I have two clients connected, for example, I would like to show two status bar icons that each indicate a client's state.

Right now I'm using standard [Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) for this for which I [update](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html) the [iconLevel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#iconLevel) as needed.

Everything works great on my Ice Cream Sandwhich phone, but my Lollipop tablet removes all but one of the icons whenever they all show the same state, e.g. when both clients are idle. If one client is idle and the other one has activity, i.e. the two icons are not the same, then both icons are shown. Also, if I open the tray, both notifications always show up, whether or not they show the same icon.

Is there a way to prevent this duplicate-icon-collapse?

I guess I could use a different set of images that all look (almost?) the same for each icon, but I'm hoping for a more elegant solution...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the hack-job solution I wanted to avoid isn't *that* bad after all:

I don't need to ship different versions of my images, or even multiple identical copies of them. It's sufficient to have multiple copies of the xml-file that defines the [LevelListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html) and then use a different one for each icon. It is ok for all LevelListDrawables to reference the same image files.

In other words: Status bar icons only ever get collapsed (on some platforms) if the [resource IDs for their icons](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#icon) **and** their [iconLevels](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#iconLevel) are identical.

This is still a pretty ugly solution, so I definitely won't accept this as the final answer. Hopefully there is a cleaner way to do this.